# How to solve libnetcdf.so.12: cannot open shared object file in pyferret?

Tags: oceanography, atmosphere-modelling, python

My pyferret was working perfectly until I had installed netCDF4 and now it is throwing up this error

```
readline: /etc/inputrc: line 19: term: unknown variable name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/cccr/msingh/anaconda3/envs/FERRET/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/pyferret/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pyferret import libpyferret
ImportError: libnetcdf.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such 
file or directory
```

Comment: Hi tech_climate, welcome to the site.  To the close voters: Please [see this meta post](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1515/6) where the consensus is that earth-science-related programming questions should be considered on-topic.

Comment: How did you install netCDF? How did you install pyferret? Looks like anaconda -- at least for pyferret. pyferret needs netCDF. Therefore, netCDF has been installed previously. There are sometimes issues with the library path, when netCDF is installed via your operating system's package manager, via anaconda and (maybe) via manual compilation. Therefore, please specify some details requested in the beginning of my comment. Additionally, please post the output of `nc-config --all` and of `conda list`. What happens if you install pyferret and a fresh conda environment?

Answer (score 4):

You need to uninstall netCDF4 as it is not compatible with pyferret library as of now.

```
pip uninstall netCDF4
```

should do.